# pipeline django social auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

this is my first project with django and i install django social auth and works fine but when i use custom pipelines the registration goes to /login-error

use python 2.6 django 1.6.2

```
#settings.py

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
'app.pipelines.get_user_avatar'
)


#pipelines.py

def get_user_avatar(strategy, user, response, is_new=False,*args,**kwargs):
url = None
if is_new and strategy.backend.name == 'facebook':
    url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % response['id']
if url:
    profile = user.get_profile()
    profile.photo = url # depends on where you saved it
    profile.save()


#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    photo = models.URLField()
```

Comment: what versions of python and django are you using? `python --version` and `django-admin.py --version`

Comment: Just FYI, Django-social-auth is now deprecated. Use it with caution.

Comment: use python 2.6 django 1.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several details in your code which aren't correct.

1. `'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session'` should be used only if  you plan to redirect the user to another view/form (breaking the processing and continuing it later)
2. Your custom pipeline is using `strategy` which is a parameter in `python-social-auth` but not `django-social-auth`.

Since you are starting I would suggest to go directly with [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) since [`django-social-auth` is deprecated](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/README.rst).

Comment: Well, I actualize to python-social-auth and fix the code as you suggested, but I have the same problem

Comment: @LuisAlfredo, update the pipeline setting to the default value http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline (you have some missing entries at the top), check if the default works, then add your pipeline function to the list and debug it if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [python social auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) instead. Django social auth is deprecated.